# use computed property names to create inner objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I create an Object like

```
const name = "email";

form = {[name]: "jon@doe.com"}
```

my `form` object looks like this

```
{email: "jon@doe.com"}
```

is it **possible to set up `name` only** that my result will looks like

```
{
  info: {
    email: "jon@doe.com"
  }
}
```

I tried:

```
const name = "info.email";

form = {[name]: "jon@doe.com"}
```

but the resulting `form` object looks like:

```
{info.email: "jon@doe.com"}
```

I also tried:

```
const name = "info[email]";

form = {[name]: "jon@doe.com"}
```

but the resulting `form` object looks like:

```
{info[email]: "jon@doe.com"}
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: no errors, the object names are wrong, I added the examples above

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I removed react context because its more a js related question

Comment: Did you change the whole post? :| Do you want me to modify the answer according to current post? @Dude

Comment: I know that I can do it with more params but the question is if its possible to do it with `name` only, sry to not be clear from beginning

Comment: You will have to use helper functions. Check it out for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wyx8z74lkk

Comment: Dude, `form = {info:{[name]: "jon@doe.com"}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dude you can't do that directly

Because Object will take key as a string and whatever you will pass it assign as key

So if you try

`const name = "info.email";
form = {[name]: "jon@doe.com"}`

It will take "info.email" as key and assign the value to that key.

If you want to create an inner object if a string has **dot "."**

you can write a function which will convert the string key to inner object.

```
    const createObject = (jsonPath, delimiter='.') => {
        const innerKeys = jsonPath.split(delimiter);
        const key = innerKeys.splice(0,1);
        if(innerKeys.length>0){
             return {[key]:createObject(innerKeys.join(delimiter), delimiter)}
        }else{
          return key[0];
        }   
   }
console.log(createObject('info.name.vishnu')); //{"info":{"name":"vishnu"}}
console.log(createObject('info,name,vishnu'), ','); //{"info":{"name":"vishnu"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will solve your problem.

```js
const createObject = (jsonPath, value) => {
  const keys = jsonPath.split('.')
  let keyValue = value;
  while(keys.length) {
    let obj = {};
    obj[keys.pop()] = keyValue;
    keyValue = Object.assign({}, obj);
  }
  return JSON.stringify(keyValue);
}

console.log(createObject('info.person.name', 'john doe'));
```

Comment: I updated the question to make it a lot simpler. My problem is that I dont like to have 2 params (name, id) I just want to set up the object via one string

Comment: @Dude Take a look now :)

Comment: `'info.name.test'`

Comment: @dfsq I mentioned that it would work only for one level deep

Comment: is there no native js solution without take care of splitting the string? I was hoping something like "info['name']" would work because I dont really want to check if there are any levels and how many. :(

Comment: @dfsq Please take a look now it's level independent but still can't avoid the split syntax.

Comment: @Dude Take a look now sorry you still can't avoid the split syntax I have made the code as minimal as possible